# How to get UITableviewcell(custom cell) values on click on button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell`(Custom cell) in which i am creating some buttons and textfields and assigning tags to the buttons and textfields. But i couldn't get button title and textfield values on click on button.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
`[((CustomCell *) cell).btn setTag:rowTag];
 [((CustomCell *) cell).textField2 setTag:rowTag+1];`

-(IBAction)submitBtnAction:(UIControl *)sender
{
    for (int i=0; i<[self->_dataArray count]; i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        NSLog(@"myIP.row %d",myIP.row);
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tblView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];
        NSLog(@"tag %d",cell.tag);
        UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:i];
        NSLog(@"btn text %@, tag %d",btn.titleLabel.text,btn.tag);
        UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:i+1];
        NSLog(@"tf text %@, tag %d",tf.text,btn.tag);

    }
}
```

I'm getting error like this

```
-[UITableViewCellContentView titleLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71844e0
2013-07-17 13:48:29.998 Text[1271:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView titleLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71844e0'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can directly access the `btn` and `textField2` properties of your cell, once you get it from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Assuming you are creating and returning instance of `CustomCell`, just typecast it to `CustomCell` instead of `UITableviewCell`. See modified code below

```
-(IBAction)submitBtnAction:(UIControl *)sender
{
        UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
        NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
        //Type cast it to CustomCell
        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tblView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];
        UIButton *btn = cell.btn;
        NSLog(@"btn text %@, tag %d",btn.titleLabel.text,btn.tag);

        UITextField *tf = cell.textField2;
        NSLog(@"tf text %@, tag %d",tf.text,btn.tag);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Amar....Is possible to get the value of textfield and button using tag for this content view....[((CustomCell *) cell).contentView setTag:rowTag];

Comment: @user1831389 I think in that case you should access button, textfield using `[cell viewWithTag:tag]` rather than `cell.contentView`.

Comment: @user1831389 What is the error you get and how are you setting the tag?

Comment: '[((CustomCell *) cell) setTag:rowTag];'                                I'm getting error like this   -[UITableViewCellContentView titleLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: @user1831389 Don't set tag to the cell, set tag to the button and textfield. The way I suggested in the answer should be the easiest to achieve what you are doing instead of tagging.

Comment: Okay @Amar... But i need one answer for this. If i set tag to cell, i ll get button and textfield values easily. And No need to set tag to all buttons and textfields in this case right??.

Comment: @user1831389 NO, setting tag to cell will not achieve what you want i.e getting the subview instances. For that you need to tag each cell subviews i.e button, textfield so that when you get cell from `[tblView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP]` you can access the subviews by tag. Accessing subviews as cell's properties will save the effort of tagging.

Comment: Okay... Thanks @Amar. But just i'm tried like this that set tag to cell.  [((CustomCell *) cell) setTag:rowTag];   NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];

        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tblView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];
NSLog(@"tf text %@",cell.textField2.text);
NSLog(@"tf1 text %@",cell.textField3.text);
NSLog(@"btn text %@",cell.btn.titleLabel.text);                   i'm getting answer for this code. Is it right way?

Comment: This line `[((CustomCell ) cell) setTag:rowTag]` does not do anything other than setting tag .. What's the use? Rest of the code is fine.

Comment: [((CustomCell ) cell) setTag:rowTag]; This code written in cellForRowAtIndexPath method to set tag for cell.

Comment: If it works for you then go ahead. If my answer has help you solve your issue, pls mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hi friends, in my logic i have to add 12 textfield in tableview cell and access each textfield's text by their tag value

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to do it:

```
-(IBAction)submitBtnAction:(UIControl *)sender
{
   UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tblView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];

    NSLog(@"cell.textField -tag :%d",cell.textField2.tag);

    NSLog(@"cell.btn -tag :%d",cell.btn.tag);

}
```

Comment: Any time @user1831389.

Comment: @satheeshwaran....Is possible to get the value of textfield and button using tag for this content view....[((CustomCell *) cell).contentView setTag:rowTag];

Comment: Yeah if you have added the textfield and the button to cell.contentView you could take it as textField.superview and btn.superView that would be cell.contentView.

Answer (score 1):

Following code to get indexPath by "event" param may be better:

```
-(IBAction)submitBtnAction:(UIControl *)sender event:(id)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPos = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView  indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPos];
    if(indexPath != nil)
    {
       //Todo: get model at indexPath, update cell or something other 
    }
}
```

submitBtn's target selector confirm change to `@selector(submitBtnAction:event:)`

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you receive an `unrecognized selector` error it's because you are accessing an object that has been replaced in memory. In your case it's probably that you are accessing a Cell that is not visible and so the `contentview` returns `nil`.

When you do your for loop you seem to access all cells which is not possible for not visible cells. For me you can only access visible cells orelse `contentview` is nil and therefore accessing `titleLabel` will give you the unrecognized selector error.

Answer (score 0):

Add a padding to the tag value. Otherwise the first row tag is 0 and that matches the content view tag, all view tags are 0 by default. Hence why you get the wrong view when tag is equal to 0.

```
#define PADDING 100
[((CustomCell *) cell).btn setTag:PADDING + rowTag];
[((CustomCell *) cell).textField2 setTag:PADDING + rowTag+1];
```

However I would change the solution to simply not use an incremental tag but a static tag. You already have the specific cell via `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` all you need are the buttons of that cell.

```
#define BUTTON_TAG 10
#define TEXT_TAG 11

cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"] autorelease];
    [((CustomCell *) cell).btn setTag:BUTTON_TAG];
    [((CustomCell *) cell).textField2 setTag:TEXT_TAG];
}

-(IBAction)submitBtnAction:(UIControl *)sender
{
    for (int i=0; i<[self->_dataArray count]; i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        NSLog(@"myIP.row %d",myIP.row);
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tblView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];
        UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:BUTTON_TAG];
        NSLog(@"btn text %@, tag %d",btn.titleLabel.text,btn.tag);
        UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:TEXT_TAG];
        NSLog(@"tf text %@, tag %d",tf.text,btn.tag);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you set your view's subview with tag 0, while view's tag property default value is 0, and `[someview viewWithTag:0]` return someview itself.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is. I pass a function to handle the event in TableViewController as a delegate to TableViewcell, and register the event to call the delegate function, and call it back. Here is how I did it

In the tableview controller cellForRow func

```
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "blablabla") as! FeedbackTableViewCell
        cell.buttonEventDelgate = buttonPressed
        cell.indexPath = indexPath //This is required to find which cell button was pressed
        return cell
```

In the TableViewcell, when the user clicks the button, I call this delegate

back in Tableviewcontroller, I would implement the delegate as follows

```
 @objc func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton, indexPath: IndexPath) -> Void {
    print("button pressed \(indexPath.row)")
  }
```

Hope this helps!!! let me know if there are better ways of doing this